# Adding a new element to an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Lets say I have and array made up of objects:

```
var points = [
  { id: 1, a: 0, b: 3 },
  { id: 2, a: 4, b: -1 },
  { id: 3, a: -1, b: 5 },
  { id: 4, a: 41, b: 2 },
  { id: 5, a: 69, b: 3 },
]
```

I want to iterate through each item and add `a` + `b` to get a new item `d`. I then want to add d within each object in the array to get a new value. When I try the below, it just adds 5 extra objects rather than appending the new element (key=value, ex: d: 3) to each individual object. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 points.forEach((item) => {
   var d = Math.abs(item.x) + Math.abs(item.y);
   console.log(d);
   points.item.push('d: ' + d);
 });
```

Comment: Your objects look to have `a` and `b` properties, not `x` and `y` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@jcbridwe**, you can use `assign()` method on **Object** to add missing property from source object to target object.

Please have a look at the below code.

> Try the below code online at http://rextester.com/EPHYV10615.

```
var points = [
  { id: 1, a: 0, b: 3 },
  { id: 2, a: 4, b: -1 },
  { id: 3, a: -1, b: 5 },
  { id: 4, a: 41, b: 2 },
  { id: 5, a: 69, b: 3 },
]

for(var index in points){
    var a = points[index].a;
    var b = points[index].b;

    Object.assign(points[index], {d: a+b});
}

console.log(points);
```

» Output

```
[ { id: 1, a: 0, b: 3, d: 3 },
  { id: 2, a: 4, b: -1, d: 3 },
  { id: 3, a: -1, b: 5, d: 4 },
  { id: 4, a: 41, b: 2, d: 43 },
  { id: 5, a: 69, b: 3, d: 72 } ]
```

Comment: I went with this solution as it added the most relevance to changes I made to the code.

Comment: Thanks **@gwydion93**.

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```js
var points = [{ id: 1, a: 0, b: 3 },{ id: 2, a: 4, b: -1 },{ id: 3, a: -1, b: 5 },{ id: 4, a: 41, b: 2 },{ id: 5, a: 69, b: 3 }];

points.forEach(o => o.d = Math.abs(o.a) + Math.abs(o.b));
console.log(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutable approach:

```
points.forEach(o => o.d = o.a + o.b);
```

Immutable approach:

```
const newPoints = points.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {d: o.a + o.b}))
```